# How to search exact value with IN() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `products` with the next `id` column

I am using `IN` function instead of `WHERE` because I expected multiples products ids

In this case only come one product id.

```
SELECT id FROM `products` WHERE id IN (00010001)
```

The above sql query returns

[image]

But that is not I expected, I expected only the first row `00010001`.

I need the value exact, How to accomplish that with `IN` function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id` is a string, so you want string comparisons:

```
SELECT proidxxx
FROM `products`
WHERE id IN ('00010001')
```

You are mixing types, so MySQL is silently converting the `id` to a number.  It is matching any `id` where the initial digits -- when converted to a number -- are equal to `10001`.